# How to permanently change attribute values using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes

I'm trying to iterate through all the features of a layer to change the value of some of its attributes. I'm using the following code:

```
from qgis.core import *
import os

working_folder = r'C:\myFolder'
fc_Opt_Prospect = os.path.join(working_folder, 'Equipm.gdb|layername=Prosp')

layer = QgsVectorLayer(fc_Opt_Prospect, 'Optimity_Prospect', 'ogr')

layer.startEditing()

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    layer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), 4, 3)
    layer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), 5, 6)

layer.commitChanges()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

When I check the attribute table of the layer I can see that no value has been changed. No error is thrown by the script.

Answer (score 2):

QGIS can't edit Esri file geodatabases, even at version 3.8:

[image]

Comment: 3.22 I believe editing was introduced to FGDB. Whether the above script will work though, not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I have realised that "layer.startEditing()" is returning false. For some reason the layer is not editable. I guess that's the reason why values are not changed at all with the script above. Now remains the question of why the layer is not editable.